# python 3.x - pyserial - stack overflow fatal error

Tags: python, fatal-error, pyserial

I wrote an Object whichs inherits from the serial.Serial Object and added some methods. In an endless loop the programm grabs information from the serial Connection. When Someone shuts the Divice on the other side down, then a SerialException notifies the user that there is a problem and calls the function again. After about 300 errors I get an stack overflow fatal error.

```
def endless():
 try:
  with serialObjectDerivedFromserial.Serial("/dev/tty/bsp") as bsp:
  #doing somthing
 except serial.SerialException:
  #notify not connected
  time.sleep(10)
  endless()
 except:
  #notify error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `endless` from itself. While it is not forbidden (it is the base of recursion), each call consumes a bit a stack. So it is no surprise that you get a stack overflow after a number of calls. The correct way is to change the recursion to an iterative processing:

```
def endless():
  while True:
     try:
      with serialObjectDerivedFromserial.Serial("/dev/tty/bsp") as bsp:
      #doing somthing
     except serial.SerialException:
      #notify not connected
      time.sleep(10)
      continue               # keep on looping on SerialException
     except:
      #notify error
     break                   # exit loop on any other case
```